# a vulnerability in quote notification plugin

Tags: php, mysql, vbulletin

The following plugin is used to serve notification for members in vbulletin forum.

a friend told me there are a possibility of vulnerability on Mysql database because of this plugin. i'm not mysql expert so i can't tell where exactly is the issue.

If anyone incase find this vulnerability i would like to know exactly what should i do to fix it.

With the plugin comes this php page that will show list of notification for the member http://textuploader.com/d1hch
 *not sure if this php script has any vulnerability*

the issue maybe related to mysqli::escape_string or PDO prepared statement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<product productid="k_quote_notifications" active="0">
    <title>Quote Notifications</title>
    <description>Notify User after being quoted</description>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <url></url>
    <versioncheckurl></versioncheckurl>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
    <codes>
        <code version="1.0.0">
            <installcode><![CDATA[$db->hide_errors();
$db->query_write("
CREATE TABLE   " . TABLE_PREFIX . "quotedatanew (
  `quoted` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `quoter` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `quotername` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '0',
  `postid` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `threadid` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `threadtitle` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '0',
  `dateline` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `hasseen` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  KEY `quoted` (`quoted`)
)
");
$db->show_errors();]]></installcode>
            <uninstallcode><![CDATA[$db->query_write("
 DROP TABLE " . TABLE_PREFIX . "quotedatanew
");]]></uninstallcode>
        </code>
    </codes>
    <templates>
        <template name="NOTI" templatetype="template" date="1401826799" username="AAA" version="1.0.0"><![CDATA[$stylevar[htmldoctype]
<html dir="$stylevar[textdirection]" lang="$stylevar[languagecode]">
<head>
<title>$vboptions[bbtitle]</title>

<style type="text/css">
.alert-box {
    color:#555;
    border-radius:10px;
    font-family:Tahoma,Geneva,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:11px;
    padding:10px 36px;
    margin:10px;
}
.alert-box span {
    font-weight:bold;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.error {
    background:#ffecec url('images/error.png') no-repeat 10px 50%;
    border:1px solid #f5aca6;
}
.success {
    background:#e9ffd9 url('images/success.png') no-repeat 10px 50%;
    border:1px solid #a6ca8a;
}
.warning {
    background:#fff8c4 url('images/warning.png') no-repeat 10px 50%;
    border:1px solid #f2c779;
}
.notice {
    background:#e3f7fc url('images/notice.png') no-repeat 10px 50%;
    border:1px solid #8ed9f6;
}
.paginate {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 3px;
}

.paginate a {
    padding:2px 5px 2px 5px;
    margin:2px;
    border:1px solid #999;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #666;
}
.paginate a:hover, .paginate a:active {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    color: #000;
}
.paginate span.current {
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;

        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #999;
        color: #FFF;
    }
    .paginate span.disabled {
        padding:2px 5px 2px 5px;
        margin:2px;
        border:1px solid #eee;
        color:#DDD;
    }

 </style>
$headinclude
</head>
<body>
$header

$navbar

<table class="tborder" cellpadding="$stylevar[cellpadding]" cellspacing="$stylevar[cellspacing]" border="0" width="100%" align="center">
<tr>
    <td class="tcat">$vbphrase[notification_page_title]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="alt1">$content</td>
</tr>
$paginate
</table>

$footer
</body>
</html>]]></template>
        <template name="TEST" templatetype="template" date="1401824077" username="AAA" version="1.0.0"><![CDATA[$stylevar[htmldoctype]
<html dir="$stylevar[textdirection]" lang="$stylevar[languagecode]">
<head>
<title>$vboptions[bbtitle]</title>
$headinclude
</head>
<body>
$header

$navbar

<table class="tborder" cellpadding="$stylevar[cellpadding]" cellspacing="$stylevar[cellspacing]" border="0" width="100%" align="center">
<tr>
    <td class="tcat">Title</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="alt1">Text</td>
</tr>
</table>

$footer
</body>
</html>]]></template>
    </templates>
    <plugins>
        <plugin active="1" executionorder="5">
            <title>Get Notifications</title>
            <hookname>global_start</hookname>
            <phpcode><![CDATA[$counter = $vbulletin->db->query_first("SELECT COUNT(*) AS id FROM quotedatanew where quoted =" . $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] . " and hasseen= '0'");
$count   = $counter['id'];
$notifi  = $vbulletin->db->query_read("SELECT * FROM quotedatanew where quoted =" . $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] . " and hasseen = '0' ORDER BY dateline DESC LIMIT 4");
while ($noti = $vbulletin->db->fetch_array($notifi)) {
    $threadurl    = $vbulletin->options['bburl'] . '/showthread.php?source=noti&p=' . $noti['postid'] . '#post' . $noti['postid'];
    $memberurl    = $vbulletin->options['bburl'] . '/member.php?u=' . $noti['quoter'];
    $notiurl      = $vbulletin->options['bburl'] . '/noti.php';
    $qoutername   = $noti['quotername'];
    $threadname   = $noti['threadtitle'];
    $phrasequote  = $vbphrase['has_quoted_your_post_in'];
    $seeallphrase = $vbphrase['see_all_noti'];
    $notihtml .= '<tr><td class="vbmenu_option" style="white-space:normal;max-width:200px;"><a href="' . $memberurl . '">' . $qoutername . '</a> ' . $phrasequote . ' <a href="' . $threadurl . '">' . $threadname . '</a></td></tr>';
}
if ($count > 4) {
    $notihtml .= '<tr><td class="vbmenu_option" style="white-space:normal;max-width:200px;"><a href="' . $notiurl . '">' . $seeallphrase . '</a></td></tr>';
}]]></phpcode>
        </plugin>
        <plugin active="1" executionorder="5">
            <title>Insert Notification</title>
            <hookname>newpost_complete</hookname>
            <phpcode><![CDATA[if ($vbulletin->options['wqm_system'] == true) {


    if (preg_match('/\[quote=(.*?)\]((?:.|\s)+?)\[\/quote\]/i', $post['message'])) {
        preg_match_all('/\[quote=(.*?)\]((?:.|\s)+?)\[\/quote\]/i', $post['message'], $quotematch);

        $quotecount = count($quotematch[0]);
        $tempcount  = 0;
        $quotearray = array();


        while ($tempcount < $quotecount) {
            $username     = explode(';', $quotematch[1][$tempcount]);
            $quoteduserid = $vbulletin->db->query_first("SELECT userid FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "user
            WHERE username = '" . $vbulletin->db->escape_string(htmlspecialchars_uni($username[0])) . "'");

            if (!in_array($quoteduserid['userid'], $quotearray)) {
                if ($quoteduserid['userid'] > 0 AND $quoteduserid['userid'] != $vbulletin->userinfo['userid']) {
                    $quotearray[] = $quoteduserid['userid'];

                    // check forum permissions
                    $quoteduserinfo = fetch_userinfo(intval($quoteduserid['userid']));
                    $forumperms     = fetch_permissions($foruminfo['forumid'], intval($quoteduserid['userid']), $quoteduserinfo);

                    if (!($forumperms & $vbulletin->bf_ugp_forumpermissions['canview']) OR !($forumperms & $vbulletin->bf_ugp_forumpermissions['canviewthreads'])) {
                        $tempcount++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (!($forumperms & $vbulletin->bf_ugp_forumpermissions['canviewothers']) AND ($threadinfo['postuserid'] != intval($quoteduserid['userid']) OR $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] == 0)) {
                        $tempcount++;
                        continue;
                    }

                    $vbulletin->db->query_write("
                    INSERT INTO " . TABLE_PREFIX . "quotedatanew (quoted,quoter,postid,threadid,threadtitle,dateline,quotername)
                    VALUES ('" . $quoteduserid['userid'] . "','" . $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] . "','" . $post['postid'] . "','" . $threadinfo[threadid] . "','" . $vbulletin->db->escape_string(htmlspecialchars_uni($threadinfo[title])) . "','" . time() . "','" . $vbulletin->db->escape_string(htmlspecialchars_uni($vbulletin->userinfo['username'])) . "')");
                }
            }
            $tempcount++;
        }
    }


}]]></phpcode>
        </plugin>
        <plugin active="1" executionorder="5">
            <title>Dismiss notification</title>
            <hookname>showthread_start</hookname>
            <phpcode><![CDATA[$postid = intval($_GET["p"]);
$source = $_GET["source"];
if ($source == "noti") {
    $vbulletin->db->query_write("update quotedatanew set hasseen = '1' where postid = '" . $postid . "' and quoted = '" . $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] . "'");
}]]></phpcode>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <phrases>
        <phrasetype name="GLOBAL" fieldname="global">
            <phrase name="delete_all_nots" date="1401999437" username="bbb" version="1.0.0"><![CDATA[Õ–› Ã„Ì⁄ «· ‰»ÌÂ« ]]></phrase>
            <phrase name="has_quoted_your_post_in" date="1401739493" username="AAA" version="1.0.0"><![CDATA[Has Quoted Your Post In]]></phrase>
            <phrase name="no_notification_text" date="1401999471" username="bbb" version="1.0.0"><![CDATA[·« ÌÊÃœ  ‰»ÌÂ«  ÃœÌœ…]]></phrase>
            <phrase name="noti_icon" date="1401829523" username="AAA" version="1.0.0"><![CDATA[Notifications]]></phrase>
            <phrase name="notification_read" date="1401825953" username="AAA" version="1.0.0"><![CDATA[Read]]></phrase>
            <phrase name="notification_unread" date="1401826023" username="AAA" version="1.0.0"><![CDATA[Unread]]></phrase>
            <phrase name="see_all_noti" date="1401810412" username="AAA" version="1.0.0"><![CDATA[See All Notification]]></phrase>
        </phrasetype>
        <phrasetype name="vBulletin Settings" fieldname="vbsettings">
            <phrase name="setting_wqm_system_desc" date="1401828337" username="AAA" version="1.0.0"><![CDATA[<style type="text/css">
body { background:#555;color:white; }
a:link, a:visited, a:active { color:white; }
.optiontitle { background:#10a113;color:#FFF;border:none; }
.button { background:#10A113;border:none;color:white;padding:6px 12px;}
.button:hover { background:#057c08; }
.tcat { color:white;background: #111;border:none; }
.tcat a:link, .tcat a:visited, .tcat a:active { color:white; }
.tfoot { background:#111;border:none; }
.alt1 { color:white;background:#333; }
.tborder { border:1px solid #000; -moz-border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;border-radius:3px;-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #000;-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #000;box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #000; }
textarea, .bginput, input.col-c, input.col-i, input.col-g { border:1px solid #000;color:#EEE;background:#444; }
.pagetitle { background:#111;color:white;border:1px solid #000;-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #000;-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #000;box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #000; }
</style>]]></phrase>
            <phrase name="setting_wqm_system_title" date="1401828337" username="AAA" version="1.0.0"><![CDATA[Enable Notifications System]]></phrase>
            <phrase name="settinggroup_Notification System" date="1401828329" username="AAA" version="1.0.0"><![CDATA[Notification System]]></phrase>
        </phrasetype>
    </phrases>
    <options>
        <settinggroup name="Notification System" displayorder="590">
            <setting varname="wqm_system" displayorder="10">
                <datatype>boolean</datatype>
                <optioncode>yesno</optioncode>
                <defaultvalue>1</defaultvalue>
            </setting>
        </settinggroup>
    </options>
    <helptopics>
    </helptopics>
    <cronentries>
    </cronentries>
    <faqentries>
    </faqentries>
</product>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only potential issue I see with this code is that queries are built up by concatenating strings instead of using prepared statements, ex:

```
        $quoteduserid = $vbulletin->db->query_first("SELECT userid FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "user
        WHERE username = '" . $vbulletin->db->escape_string(htmlspecialchars_uni($username[0])) . "'");
```

This exposes queries to potential sql injections attacks.

I see in the code that precautions are taken, for example the `username` in the where clause is composed with:

```
username = '" . $vbulletin->db->escape_string(htmlspecialchars_uni($username[0])) . "'"
```

The `username` is escaped `db->escape_string` that is supposed to prevent injection attacks. But a bug in that function may result in the code being not safe.

The only recomended and bullet proof way to do queries is using prepared staetements.

Here the link for [prepared statements mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Prepared statements let you pass a parameter to be used in a query (ex. the username) **directly** to mysqli or pdo. With this approach there is no way for a character or characters sequence in the parameter to "break" the query as it could happen when the query is built up by concatenation of static strings and (escaped) variable values.

---

If you want to improve the code you have to substitute each query in its "prepared statement form".

Prepared statements queries are easy to do (just check if `$vbullettin->db` is a mysqli or PDO connection to use the correct methods).

As parameters must then be passed **unescaped** you should check what `$vbulletin->db->escape_string` actually does (in the example) in order for the data in stored in the db maintain its format.

Comment: Is there any way to reach you? email or any kind of contact

Comment: @user3693856, hi, I'm sorry, at the moment I don't give my contact details on SO. Anyway if you need help with the issue above I can't help because I'm too busy now. Of course if something in my answer is not clear just point it out and I'll do my best to improve it.

Comment: sadly i'm not mysql expert. Any advice to contact someone who could handle this as freelancer? i used freelancer.com and no one understand what i need even after explaining what you said.

Comment: @user3693856 honestly I'm not that good at finding programmers, it's a problem for me too. Anyway you should search for a PHP developer first. Since you are here you may give a look at http://stackoverflow.com/jobs